# Using dind on drone.io

Tags: continuous-integration, drone.io

I'm trying move from gitlab ci to drone.io. But I can't make DIND works well as on gitlab. Above is how I did on gitlab.

```
variables:
  NODE_ENV: 'test'
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay

image: gitlab/dind

services:
  - docker:dind

cache:
  untracked: true

stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - docker info
    - docker-compose --version
    - docker-compose pull
    - docker-compose build
  after_script:
    - docker-compose down
  script:
    - docker-compose run --rm api yarn install
```

How can I create an equivalent drone file ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the services section to start the docker daemon.

```
pipeline:
  ping:
    image: docker
    environment:
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///drone/docker.sock
    commands:
      - sleep 10 # give docker enough time to initialize
      - docker ps -a

services:
  docker:
    image: docker:dind
    privileged: true
    command: [ '-H', 'unix:///drone/docker.sock' ]
```

Note that we change the default location of the docker socket and write to the drone volume which is shared among all containers in the pipeline:

```
command: [ '-H', 'unix:///drone/docker.sock' ]
```

Also note that we need to run the dind container in privileged mode. The privileged flag can only be used by trusted repositories. You will therefore need a user administrator to set the trusted flag to true for your repository in the drone user interface.

```
privileged: true
```

Comment: It is also possible to use the docker daemon from the host instead of docker-in-docker image. You need to mount the docker sock into the the pipeline. See [drone io: Host Volumes](https://docs.drone.io/pipeline/docker/syntax/volumes/host)